# H-bridge output filtering

Tags: h-bridge, low-pass, allegro

I'm driving A4952 motor driver with about 25khz PWM signal, with a simple coil connected as a load between OUT1 and OUT2. VBB is variable, testing with 15V but changing it doesn't alter the results.

As long as it's running with the PWM signal, coil works fine, and the output signal from the driver looks pretty much like input, only amplified. What I'm doing at the input is changing the PWM duty cycle on inputs so that it gives roughly 50 Hz sine wave.

As soon as I try to put a filter capacitor above certain value between output and the ground, the driver goes into fault, and that's the issue that I have been unable to figure out.

The thing has LSS pin which is meant for current limiting resistor. Initially I had about 0.25 ohms there, but eventually I just tied it directly to the ground.

Any cap that I place between output pin and ground that's more than 100nf or so, will drive it into fault condition. So I placed a small inductor, about 3μH in series with output, and placed the cap after that, same story.

I've tried to turn off the other phase of PWM entirely, lower the PWM frequency, and a bunch of other things, no luck. The driver just goes to fault as soon as I try and filter the output. (LC filter, RC filter, load connected, load off, makes no difference.)

Any ideas why this might be happening? The datasheet is not super clear about how the LSS is internally wired either.

Comment: The impedance of your cap at 25kHz and harmonics thereof is low enough that you're loading your bridge beyond its current limit.  The motor inductance should filter out the PWM frequency, why do you need additional filtering?  EMI?

Comment: EMI and in the final circuit that generated signal will not go straight to the coil but through other AC circuitry. I'd like to get something close to a sine wave.

Comment: You need to show a circuit of the setup with the inductor and capacitor - presumably you should be only using one-half of the H-bridge for this test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to filter the output of your PWM you'll need an LC filter. The topology (series L + C to ground) is okay, but your values are way off- 3\$\mu\$H is not much better than a short at 25kHz, and without that, the current will be \$ C\cdot \$\$dv \over dt \$, which is going to be very high since the MOSFET switches quickly.

Suppose you want a 5kHz cutoff frequency (\$\omega_0\$ ~= 31000) and your load resistance is 15 ohms. [Here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa119a/sloa119a.pdf) is some useful info.

[image]

For a Butterworth response C = 1.5\$\mu\$F. L = 700\$\mu\$H

Comment: Spehro is correct, and don't forget you need a non-polarized capacitor.

Comment: Basically, it should be safe to start with as large inductor that has saturation current a couple times the average power draw as i have on hand right ?

That will be a large coil, maybe need to have more poles to use smaller components

Comment: Of the required inductance, yes. It takes a physically large inductor to filter a high current at a relatively low 25kHz frequency.